# How to restrict editing of records to the logged-in user?

Tags: django

Sorry, I am still new to Django, hopefully the question isn't out of place.

When I have the following in my template:

```
<td><a href="/contact/edit/?id{{ item.id }}">{{ item.last_name }}</a></td>
```

By clicking on last name the user will be redirected to the following link in order to edit it.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/edit/?id=1
```

But then what prevents any logged in user to just inject a different id in there on the browser and edit a record that doesn't belong to him?

**Update**

I just had an idea when I read the comment and answer below.  Rather than using a third party app, couldn't I just create a UserProfile for each user and attach a unique company wide uuid.uuid1().  Each time a loggedin user attempts to edit something, his unique company uuid will be also passed in the link as an additional parameter.

On the edit side, it would harvest this guid and compare it against the logged in user and see if they match. If they do match, he is authorized to proceed with the editing, otherwise he will be redirected.

What do you think? Any weaknesses?

Comment: In the form.save() in edit page you need to check if the user has permissions to edit this user. You cannot make them not to modify the URL... Or on page load of the edit page to check the permissions and to redirect if needed...

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea. I have a proposal. Check out my updated question. What do you think?

Comment: Why not simply check the permission in the form view and deny any unauthorized operation, it is the standard usage IMO

Comment: @okm IMO all logged in users should have the permission to edit contacts. But only their own contacts!!! If handleing this is possible, please point me to the documentation to understand it better.

Comment: What's the relationship between user and contacts?

Comment: @okm users from Company A can create/edit any number of contacts. But he shall not be able to see or edit contacts of Company B. There is no relationship in the models between User and Contact.

Comment: You could check whether the company of the contact to be viewed/edited is in the companies that the `request.user` works in, in the beginning of a view. If the permission checking is heavily used in your app, you could take advantage of Django Permission API and library such as `django-guardian` as suggested.

Comment: @okm I have downloaded django-guardian as you suggested and went through the doc. e.g. it creates an employees group and give that group permission to change tasks. Therefore I could create for each company a separate group and assign their users to the group. However each group will still have the same 'change_task' permission on tasks. This plugin seems to handle permissions based on the hierarchy within a group (who has what privilege). My problem is different. All users within the same group should only be able to see and edit the rows their group has created. Please enlighten me if wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using Django `auth`, always rely on the `session` mechanism to identify an user instead of making some other id such as `uuid1()` (except, for example, when you need extra sessions in an e-commerce site under `HTTPS`).

For the permission part, you could check the ownership directly, mainly as described by [Koliber Services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11226230/165603). The relationships between `Company`, `User` and `Contact` are crucial for the logic of permission checking. There are many ways to model the relationships and thus the code would differ much. For example:

```
# a modeling way
User.company -> Company : an user belongs to a company
Contact.contributor -> User : a contact is contributed by an user, would be invalid is user is leaving the company
# could check accessibility by 
can_view = contact.contributor.company_id == current_user.company_id

# another modeling way
User.company -> Company : an user belongs to a company
Contact.company -> Company : a contact info is owned by a company, does not share globally
# could check accessibility by
can_view = contact.company_id == current_user.company_id
```

When `can_view` is `False`, user should get a 403 for his unauthorized attempting and get logged.

Normally the above method is enough for content protection(not yet in Django Admin). However, when you have many different types of permission checking and even row-permission checkings, it's better to use some uniform permission API.

Take Django-guardian for example, you could simply map companies to groups and `assign` `can_view` permission for a contact for the group representing the user's company. Or, `assign` the `can_view` permission to all users in a company when a contact is created by using signal or celery task.

Furthermore, you could use `/contact/1/edit/` instead of `/contact/edit/?id=1`. In this way the `int(request.GET('id'))` part is moved to urlconf like `r'^contact/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'`, less code and much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Django's new [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views//), e.g. the generic [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#updateview), you can extend the `dispatch` handler.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    handler = super(MyEditView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # Only allow editing if current user is owner
    if self.object.author != request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden(u"Can't touch this.")
    return handler
```

In this case, the code verifies that the `author` field of the model object corresponds to the currently logged in user, before even handling the rest of the request.

You can see a reallife example of this in a [project of mine](https://github.com/studentenportal/web/blob/5a3cb53d032175c354ed05cea604be4dd9325ef7/apps/front/views.py#L84).

Comment: This is a great solution, at least it worked for me anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party apps that does what you want, its called "row-level permission" where you can give different users different access to specific objects, "Row level" comes from SQL where each object is a row in the database

I use [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/) to do the job

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You just gave me an idea. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the function handling the saving of the data, check to see if the object being edited has the same ID as the presently logged in user.

For example, if the object in question is called EmailPrefs and it has a field called user_id:

1. Load the EmailPrefs object with the ID of the object being edited
2. If the user_id does not match the current user, stop further processing
3. Modify the EmailPrefs object
4. Save the EmailPrefs object to the database

Comment: Very good. I think this is even better than the idea I suggested. Since you won't need to pass the id as an additional parameter anymore and would check it automatically behind the scenes. Therefore upon creating any instance of any model an additional field with the user_id shall be stored within the object. And upon editing the object, this id has to match the one of the logged in user in order to proceed.  Have I understood you correctly?