# How to restrict editing of records to record's owner in Django?

Tags: python, django

I know that this question has been asked/addressed in other threads, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225704/how-to-restrict-editing-of-records-to-the-logged-in-user/11226230#11226230). However, for some reason, the proposed solution does not work for me.

I created a Django app to manage our lab's strains. My goal is to allow only the user that created an entry in the strain database, or a superuser, to change said entry.

I have the following model in models.py:

```
class strain (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length = 150, blank=False)

    [...more fields here...]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```

And the following in admin.py:

```
class StrainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'mating_type', 'parental_strain', 'user_id')
    list_display_links = ('id', )
    search_fields = ('id', 'name')
    list_per_page = 25
    list_filter = ('user', )
    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(StrainAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['user'].initial = request.user
        return form
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = super(StrainAdmin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.object.user_id != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden("Can't touch this.")
        handler
```

From what I read on Stack Overflow (see above) and elsewhere, I thought that the best way to achieve my goal was to extend the dispatch handler as such:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    handler = super(StrainAdmin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if self.object.user_id != request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("Can't touch this.")
    handler
```

However, this solution does not seem to actually do anything: a user can still change both their records and those created by other users.

I am using Django 1.9. What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue that I raised above, as suggested by @daniel-rosman as follows

```
  def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is not None:
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else: 
                if obj.user != request.user:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
```

This works in the sense that if a user tries to access another user's record, he/she will get a 403 Forbidden page. However, implementing this solution will block access to/grey out the list view for `strain` (i.e. the table that shows the records for a model). For a superuser as well! This is somewhat of unexpected consequence.

Also, I wonder if there may be another way to allow a user to see a record but not change it unless he/she created it. One, perhaps not so elegant, way could be to hide the "Save" button in the `/change/` view if the logged user is not the same as the one that created the record. Maybe by overriding `change_view`. But getting the attribute for an object (i.e. strain) from within `change_view` does not seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting confused with class-based views; ModelAdmin doesn't use a `dispatch` method;

In the admin, the best thing to do is to override [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) and check `obj.user_id`

Comment: Thanks @daniel-roseman for the tip. I read on has_change_permission and have come up the this code to replace the above_shown dispatch method:

Comment: `def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):`  
        `if request.user.is_superuser:`  
            `return True`  
        `else:`  
            `if self.user != request.user:`  
                `return False`  
            `else:`  
                `return True`

Comment: However, when I implement it, I receive the following error: "AttributeError: 'StrainAdmin' object has no attribute 'user'". Chnaging user to user_id doesn't solve the issue. I'm clearly a newbie at using Django, but the information on how to override has_change_permission is not very detailed. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the else, you should be comparing `obj.user`, not `self.user` (self is the Admin class itself, hence the error). You probably want to check `obj is not None` first.